# Mongoid has_many / belongs_to has 'undefined method' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I want to use has_many/belongs_to in my mongoid models.

I already use that in other models and it works well, but in the codes below occurs

```
undefined method `options' for class `Product' error.
```

Models :

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :options

  field :name, type: String
  ...
end

class Option
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :product

  field :name, type: String
end
```

Controller :

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(id: :desc)
  end
end
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: What if instead of options you can give `class Opt self.collection_name = 'options'` and in Product use `has_many :opts`

Comment: @RajarshiDas Thanks, but noting changed.

Comment: on a lighter note, options is a reserved word change this to some other word

Comment: @G.B Thanks it works!

Comment: Happy to know that it worked. Kindly accept the answer as well then

Answer (score 1):

You are using options which is a reserved word. Change `Option` to some other word like `ProductOption`